# How to search for slow queries on Android SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am developping and Android application and want to find the slowest/more expansive sqlite queries running on my device to fine tune them.
Which query can I use and how can I run it on my device database ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism that already times your queries.

You have to add your own logging:

```java
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
Cursor c = db.query(...);
try {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        ...
    }
} finally {
    c.close();
}
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.d(TAG, "query time: " + (t2 - t1));
```

And please note that SQLite computes result rows on demand, so you cannot easily isolate the query execution time from the time that your own code needs to handle the result rows.